# What is the equivalent of the gremlin queries in gremlin javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

How can I write the 3 gremlin queries below with gremlin javascript, please?

```
gremlin> g.V.filter{it.name.matches(".*ark.*")}.name

g.V().filter({ it.getProperty("name").contains("ark") })

g.V().filter(label().is('person'))
```

Answer (score 5):

`filter()` traversal method expects a predicate or a traversal. Predicates using lambdas are not yet supported on the JavaScript GLV, I've filed a ticket for it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2001

```
const gremlin = require('gremlin');
const __ = gremlin.process.statics;

// Use the anonymous traversal
g.V().filter(__.label().is('person'))
```