# Using `filter` lambda in gremlin with javascript

Tags: javascript, orientdb, gremlin, predicate

I am using OrientDb with JavaScript and I have tried with startingWith, containing, endingWith, notContaining, notEndingWith, notStartingWith predicates unsuccessfully. Maybe is a wrong implementation from my side but I have not found documentation about how to use.
I've been looking for a way to filter with lambdas to get a sql `like` behavior but have not been successful.  I tried to use the method [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19099817/858040), but it is not working on JavaScript. When using the predicates the answer is an error.

I've tried that too:
[What is the equivalent of the gremlin queries in gremlin javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51251768/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-gremlin-queries-in-gremlin-javascript)

My current JavaScript code:

```
import * as gremlin from 'gremlin';
const traversal = gremlin.process.AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal;
const DriverRemoteConnection = gremlin.driver.DriverRemoteConnection;
const TextPredicated = gremlin.process.TextP;
const authenticator = new gremlin.driver.auth.PlainTextSaslAuthenticator('usr', 'pwd');
const remote = new DriverRemoteConnection(
    'ws://localhost:8182/gremlin', {
    authenticator,
    traversalSource: 'g'
});

remote.addListener('socketError', (error) => { console.log(`socketError: ${error}`); });

(async () => {
    try {
        remote.open();
        const g = await traversal().withRemote(remote);
        const results = await g.V()
            .where('username', TextPredicated.containing('john'))
            .toList();
        console.log(results);
        remote.close();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } finally {
        remote.close();
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what your error is, but I think your Gremlin should use `has()` rather than `where()`:

```
const results = await g.V()
        .has('username', TextPredicated.containing('john'))
        .toList();
```

Also note that `TextP` did not become available until TinkerPop 3.4.0 so you'd need to be sure that your graph (in your case, OrientDB) supports at least this version of TinkerPop.